# How to troubleshoot if config.xml was deleted in weblogic

Tags: xml, linux, weblogic, config, middleware

Please help me anyone, i'm recently faced one interview i have gotten one question like this
how to troubleshoot if config.xml was deleted in weblogic?

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming you do not have any backup and it's purely the config.xml file, you could try the following:

- If you have a WebLogic cluster spread over different machines (and thus different domain directories), a copy of the config directory is copied to every other domain home.
- If you enabled automatic configuration backups earlier (and a configArchive directory exists), you can find a copy of your configuration in the JAR files there.
- If you recently enrolled new machines in the domain you would have used the domain pack utility, which created an archive file which also includes the config.xml, but this configuration could be outdated.
- If the admin server is still running, you could try making any configuration change, this will regenerate the config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic keeps the old configuration file for scenarios like this you can find a backup in :
`/Middleware_HOME/user_projects/domains/DOMAIN_NAME/servers/domain_bak/config_prev/config.xml`
This file is of the time admin server as booted. so any changes made after admin server are lost.